# is It possible to check whether the alarm clock starts or ends?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alexa-voice-service

I have recently been working on the development of the [AVS Alerts Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/alerts.html) module.

There was a problem with [AlertStarted Event](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/alerts.html#alertstarted):

> **AlertStarted Event**
>
> The AlertStarted event must be sent to AVS when an alert is triggered at its scheduled time.

At the beginning or end of the alarm I need to call the corresponding request to tell alexa server.

Now I don't know how to capture the state of the alarm clock.
Is there any way to do this?

Can notifications be implemented? How?

thanks!

Comment: Have you created alarms in your app? or do you want to get them from Alarm App?

Comment: Here is full detail about when to call AlertStarted method https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/alerts-overview.html

Comment: @aBilal17 I mean when an alert is triggered but my app is killed by user,  how to execute my code